# extjs how to parametrize a component

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to pass two parameters `oneOfAll` and `twoOfAll` into a container. From the `initComponent` function I do:

```
initComponent: function () {
       this.callParent(arguments);
       console.log('Results', this.oneOfAll, this.twoOfAll);
}
```

and the browser's console prints the correct data, but when:

```
items: [
          {
              xtype: 'button',
              text: 'Other click',
              id: 'buttonClick',
              handler: function(item) {
                  Ext.Msg.alert('Other Click', '!!!' + this.oneOfAll);
              }
          },
          {
              xtype: 'button',
              text: 'CLICK',
              id: 'buttonClick_2',
              handler: function(item) {
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Other Click', '!!!' + this.twoOfAll);
              }
           }
      ]
```

these values are not seen by the container config, both times `undefined` is returned.

I have this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sk3

How can I pass these parameters into the container and be seen by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set reference to current component in `initComponent` method and use them in child component.

Take a look on example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2skh

Comment: your solution works for the given scenario, but what if I need to change only a property? I mean, I need to set the `id` or even what if I need to set the `width` of an item? Are there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about `what if I need to change only a property?`. What property? In which component? Give a specific example.

Comment: that is to say: I want to set the container `id`, or an item `width`, or any other property coming from the parent component, but what if I can't set it into the initComponent... is there any way around?

Comment: You can do it by `constructor` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the handler, `this` refers to the item object, not your component.

To fix this, you could try accessing the component by ID, and get its property directly.

For example (using your `mypanel` id from your fiddle):

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Other click',
    id: 'buttonClick',
    handler: function (item) {
        var cmp = Ext.getCmp('mypanel');
        Ext.Msg.alert('Other Click', '~~!!' + cmp.oneOfAll);
    }
},
```

Comment: I have the same question for you: what if I have no handler and therefore no `item` object? What if what I need to set is a property? I know there are different scenarios, but, how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your handler has a different scope and configs which you set are in different.

In order to fetch the values, get the reference of that component first and then try to access.

```
handler: function(item) {       
   Ext.Msg.alert('Other Click', '!!!' + item.up().oneOfAll);
   Ext.Msg.alert('Other Click', '!!!' + item.up().twoOfAll);
}
```

Comment: What if I have no handler? What if what I need to set is the container `id`? How do I proceed?